# How to read the slash in a “ 1/1 plain weave” or “1/4 satin”?

Tags: terminology, pronunciation, slash

Is it pronounced as *one-**by**-one* or as *one-**to**-one* when read out?

Please note that this use is related to the **binding structure of textiles**.

Here is an example of usage from [Role of Yarn Tension in Weaving](https://books.google.com/books?id=35XwCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA155&dq=1%2F4%20satin&pg=PA155#v=onepage&q&f=false) by  Samir Kumar Neogi (©2016):

> It is observed that when the weave is changed from 4 / 1 satin to 1 / 4 satin， 
>   the average warp tensions at shedding and beaten-up increase (Fig. 7 ．38A ）

Comment: You might try asking at our sister-site for [crafts.se].

Comment: It might help if you provide a link for some context. [Do you mean like what's happening here](https://books.google.com/books?id=dZgoAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA500#v=onepage&q&f=false) or [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=35XwCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA155&dq=1%2F4%20satin&pg=PA155#v=onepage&q&f=false)?

Comment: Hi, thank you, yes the context of the second link your offer is suitable. I will try to add it to the description of my question. I am new here, will learn to do.

Comment: Hi dasliit and welcome to Stack Exchange. I thank you for heeding my advice. Now I hate to be a bother, but  I just wanted to mention that here at Stack Exchange, [we have certain requirements for making quotations](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).  In addition to properly delimiting the quotation, as you have, you should also include at least the name of the source material, and its author, in plain text (since links break).  I took the liberty of fixing this for you with an edit, but I thought I'd expressly inform you of this anyway, just for the sake of future reference.

Answer (score 3):

It is best to use what the slash is normally used for which is fractions or more specifically ratios. The sentence can be read as "the weave is changed from 'four to one' satin to 'one to four' satin". The ratio of A to B is what the text is about. The slash has just been used as shorthand.

Comment: Hi Elliot: This looks like the start of a good answer. However, for the purposes of curating website quality, we prefer for answers to include [some sort of basis for believing them](https://tinyurl.com/mcov4oq). The easiest, and most helpful way to do this is with references. Citing [a math book that explains how to read ratios](https://tinyurl.com/ybxu2m5h), and [style guide to show that ratios may alternatively be written with a slash](https://tinyurl.com/yazndn9n) This would do much to convince people who are uncertain of your answer, such as questioners, that your answer is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a ratio of one-to-one or one-to-four or whatever. In plain textual writing, I'd write it out that way. If it's technical writing, the slash construction is fine, as long as that's what the particular industry conventionally does. Beware, though, of using technical contractions like that in "standard" writing for ordinary civilians and normal people.